# Изменение логических значений объектов в объекте

Tags: javascript

Есть, допустим, такие данные

```
options: {
  user1: {
   userOption1: false,
   userOption2: false,
   userOption3: false,
   userOption4: false,
},
  user2: {
   userOption1: false,
   userOption2: false,
   userOption3: false,
   userOption4: false,
},
  user3: {
   userOption1: false,
   userOption2: false,
   userOption3: false,
   userOption4: false,
},
  user4: {
   userOption1: false,
   userOption2: false,
   userOption3: false,
   userOption4: false,
}
}
```

И у нас есть 16 чекбоксов, которые должны быть привязаны к этим значениям. Есть ли какой-то выход, кроме как на 16 чекбоксов вручную повесить все это?

Comment: Но как-то ведь эти чекбоксы обозначены, чтобы они друг от друга отличались?

Comment: Никогда не используйте цифры в именах переменных. Массивы для чего придумали? Надеюсь это просто пример, а не реальный код.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```js
let state = {
  user1: {
   userOption1: false,
   userOption2: false,
   userOption3: false,
   userOption4: false,
},
  user2: {
   userOption1: false,
   userOption2: false,
   userOption3: false,
   userOption4: false,
},
  user3: {
   userOption1: false,
   userOption2: false,
   userOption3: false,
   userOption4: false,
},
  user4: {
   userOption1: false,
   userOption2: false,
   userOption3: false,
   userOption4: false,
}
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=\"checkbox\"]"), e => e.addEventListener('change', e => {
  state["user" + e.target.parentNode.dataset.user]["userOption" + e.target.dataset.id] = e.target.checked;
  
  console.log(state);
}));
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-user="1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="3">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="4">
  </div>
  <div data-user="2">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="3">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="4">
  </div>
  <div data-user="3">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="3">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="4">
  </div>
  <div data-user="4">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="3">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var options = {
  user1: {
    userOption1: false,
    userOption2: false
  },
  user2: {
    userOption1: false,
    userOption2: false
  }
};

function clickCheckbox() {
  var user = this.dataset.user;
  var option = this.dataset.option;
  options[user][option] = this.checked;

  console.log(options);
}

var checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
  checks[i].addEventListener("change", clickCheckbox);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-user="user1" data-option="userOption1">
<input type="checkbox" data-user="user1" data-option="userOption2">
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" data-user="user2" data-option="userOption1">
<input type="checkbox" data-user="user2" data-option="userOption2">
```